# Remover Evento/Função - jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function paper_collapse() {
    $(".collapse-card").paperCollapse();
}
```

Esta função é chamada sempre quando a pagina é carregada.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    paper_collapse();
});
```

Agora, através de um evento `click`, irei adicionar alguns itens ao objeto, e novamente precisarei chamar a função `paper_collapse`.

Acontece que, quando faço isso, a aplicação tem um comportamento contrário ao que preciso, isto, porque esta mesma função já foi chamada uma vez no carregamento da página.

O que eu quero é, remover a função que foi chamada anteriormente no carregamento da pagina.

Isto é possivel ?

Exemplo: `$(paper_collapse).unbind();` ou `.off`

Comment: Inclua o seu código, adicionar novos itens você quer dizer novos elementos nos itens da lista atual ou novos itens à lista?

Comment: novos itens a lista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dando uma rápida olhada no código da biblioteca eu não encontrei recursos para destruir ou remover os comportamentos depois de inicializado. Você teria que implementar a funcionalidade que deseja.
[GitHub - paper-collapse](https://github.com/alexander-ruehle/paper-collapse)

Mas você não precisa remover e reaplicar o `collapsePaper()` só porque alterou seu `DOM`. Você pode fazer dessa forma, ao adicionar os novos items, crie os elementos adicionando uma class `pending-paper` e aplique o `collapsePaper()` apenas neles. Depois remova a classe para não ter problemas ao adicionar novos itens.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.collapse-card').paperCollapse();

});

$("#adicionar").on('click', function(){
  
  //Ao criar um novo item, adicione a classe pending-paper
  $("#lista-container").append(
        '<div class="collapse-card pending-paper">' 
        +'  <div class="collapse-card__heading">'
        +'    <div class="collapse-card__title">'
        +'      <i class="fa fa fa-smile-o fa-2x fa-fw"></i>'
        +'      Novo Item adicionado'
        +'    </div>'
        +'  </div>'
        +'  <div class="collapse-card__body">'
        +'    Olar!'
        +'  </div>'
        +'</div>');
   //Aplica o paperCollapse() e remove a classe pending-paper     
   $('.pending-paper').paperCollapse();
   $('.pending-paper').removeClass('pending-paper');
});
```

```css
@import 'https://bbo-code.com/assets/application-36f0df9269ad8b7eb9e05875a73766db8e7b3330bc5609acfb7334150dc334bf.css';
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans';
@import 'https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://bbo-code.com/assets/application-5b0731ecc07adfb7c609f672d05f786a5cf6c9c25f3d16fa3cb841eaae11613b.js"></script>
<div class="flex-container row justify-content-center pb2">
      <div id="lista-container" class="flex-item col-sm-9">
        <div class="collapse-card">
          <div class="collapse-card__heading">
            <div class="collapse-card__title">
              <i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
              Well, hello there
            </div>
          </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<center>
<button id="adicionar">Adicionar</button>
</center>
```

Comment: Perfeito cara!
Funcionou para mim.
Obrigado..